# Grails not adding jars to classpath from BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm using the following code inside BuildConfig.groovy:

```
  dependencies{
       compile (
             'com.oracle:oamasdk-api:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:identitystore:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:identityutils:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:jps-api:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:jps-common:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:jps-internal:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:jps-ee:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:jps-unsupported-api:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:oraclepki:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:osdt_cert:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:osdt_core:11.1.2.3.0',
             'com.oracle:osdt_xmlsec:11.1.2.3.0'
  )
```

After adding this I am running clean, compile, refresh-dependencies.  During the compile it downloads the jars and I am able to find them inside .grails/ivy-cache/com.oracle.  The issue however is they never make it to the grails-dependencies.  Is there a step I am missing?

I'm using grails 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like restarting eclipse and doing a right click Grails Tools > Refresh Dependencies, instead of grails command line, did the trick.